# Logic behind equations and inequalities involvin absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

[image]

I understand the upper section, but the lower "More generally" doesnt make sense. I m wondering why its -- for example in |x-a|<D -- why the lowest value is a-D, why -D? And same goes with the understanding of the highest value a+D. Couldnt it be anything else and why not/ why yes? I m trying to intuitively grasp what is happening, if someone is able to explain me the logic, i m very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the lower results from the upper ones. For example:

$\begin{array}{c}&&& |x - a| & \leq & D \\
\implies & -D & \leq & x - a & \leq & D \\
\implies & -D + a & \leq & x & \leq & D + a & \mbox{ adding } a \\
\implies & a - D & \leq & x & \leq & a + D \end{array}$

In the second line, we take $|x| \leq D \implies -D \leq x \leq D$ from the upper set of equations and replace $x$ with $x - a$.

If you want an intuitive way to think about it, $|x - a|$ represents the distance between the point $x$ and the value $a$, ignoring the sign. So $|x - a| \leq D$ means "the point $x$ is at most $D$ distance away from the value $a$".